# Pass variables to Function()

Tags: javascript, function, eval

I wish to use the `Function` javascript feature instead of "eval", for implementing the ability to use comparison operators inside a filtering input field.

```
function test(){
 let x = 5, y = 10, operator = '>';
 return Function("return x" + operator + "y")(x, y);
}

console.log(test());
```

The code above throws an error, x, y appear undefined in the Function.

So how can I pass external variables to Function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each parameter referenced in the function body should be a leading argument to the function, in string format.

```js
function test(){
 let x = 5, y = 10;
 return Function('x', 'y', "return x>y")(x, y);
}

console.log(test());
```